# Java Sorting Even and Odd Numbers

Tags: java

I'm in a high school programming class right now and my instructions were to create a program that stores the random numbers in an array that's sorted by even and then odd numbers. Here's my code so far, I have no idea why it's not working. It keeps printing out 0's even though I'm supposed to generate numbers above 1. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! :D

```
    Random rnd = new Random();

    int randomNumArray[] = new int[10];
    int evenArray[] = new int[10];
    int oddArray[] = new int[10];
    int countEven = 0,countOdd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumArray.length; i++)
    {
        randomNumArray[i] = rnd.nextInt(100) + 1;
        System.out.println(randomNumArray[i]);
        
        if (randomNumArray[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            evenArray[i] = randomNumArray[i];
            countEven++;
        }
        else if (randomNumArray[i] % 2 == 1)
        {
            oddArray[i] = randomNumArray[i];
            countOdd++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < countEven; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(evenArray[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < countOdd; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(oddArray[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify.  There is no middle number of an even sized array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are storing the values in `evenArray` and `oddArray` at index `i`, which is not necessarily the "next unused space" in the array you're writing to. Let's say the first number (when `i = 0`) is even and the second (when `i = 1`) is odd; when the second number is stored by `oddArray[i] = randomNumArray[i];`, it will be stored at index 1, but it is the first odd number so it should be in `oddArray` at index 0 instead.

To solve this, you can use `countEven` and `countOdd` as the correct indices to write to; for example, when `countOdd` is 0 then there are no odd numbers yet, so index 0 is the correct place to write the first one. So you can change these two lines:

```java
        if (randomNumArray[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            // changed here
            evenArray[countEven] = randomNumArray[i];
            countEven++;
        }
        else if (randomNumArray[i] % 2 == 1)
        {
            // changed here
            oddArray[countOdd] = randomNumArray[i];
            countOdd++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change these lines

```java
evenArray[countEven] = randomNumArray[i];

oddArray[countOdd] = randomNumArray[i];
```

... instead of

```java
evenArray[i] = randomNumArray[i];

oddArray[i] = randomNumArray[i];
```